# How to display date time field as blank or 1900-01-01 if the date time value is null using sql command

Tags: sql, datetime, singlestore

I am using Mem SQL and have to display date time field as '1099-01-01' or blank if the date-time field is null

Comment: [COALESCE](https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/reference/sql-reference/conditional-functions/coalesce.html)

Answer (score 1):

To display empty

```
select COALESCE(DateColumn,'')  from TableName;
```

To Display Static Value

```
select COALESCE(DateColumn,'1900-01-01')  from TableName;
```